# Review History for Review Tasks (beta) is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

When I look at the History tab for "Suggested Edits" in Review beta, my history is missing, and I'm greeted with this message only:

> *You have not reviewed any suggested edits yet.*

The Stats tab, however, indicates, that I've reviewed 102 edit suggestions. What's wrong?

*EDIT:* The same applies to "Low Quality Posts", and according to [j0k](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/182741) to "Close Votes" as well (I can't see that myself since I don't have the necessary rep).

*EDIT2:* To the best of our knowledge, the history was available yesterday.

Comment: Same thing here!

Comment: The problem is for all review type (Low Quality Posts, Suggested Edits & Close Votes). You should add the [tag:review] tag.

Comment: @j0k You're right. Didn't look at the other types before...

Comment: The bug is probably introduced in the latest build. I remember clearly that the history is there when I review close votes yesterday.

Comment: Yes, @nhahtdh, you're probably right. I believe that I saw the history yesterday as well.

Comment: @ChristofferLette are you able to see history right now?

Comment: It works for me (for the 3 of them) now.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Yes, the history is back. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an issue but has been fixed and deployed in the current production release.